# How to get hours difference between now and next friday

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to get hours difference between now and next friday 18:00 (weekend) using momentjs, I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
public getWeekend() {
    const nextFriday = moment().weekday(4)
    nextFriday.hours(18) // Weekend time: 18:00
    nextFriday.minutes(0)
    nextFriday.seconds(0)

    const diff = moment(nextFriday.diff(moment()))
    console.log(diff.days())
    if (diff.days() * 24 + diff.hours() <= 99) {
      return nextFriday.toString()
    } else {
      return 0
    }
  }
}
```

console.log(diff.days()) is printing 6 days whereas we are Wednesday

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
function getWeekend() {

    const nextFriday = moment().weekday(4)
        nextFriday.hours(18) // Weekend time: 18:00
        nextFriday.minutes(0)
        nextFriday.seconds(0)

        const diffHours = moment.duration(nextFriday.diff(moment())).asHours()
        console.log(`${diffHours} hours`) // 31.7 hours
        if (diffHours <= 99) {
          return nextFriday.toString()
        } else {
          return 0
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommended to use `moment`

```
const diff = moment.duration(nextFriday.diff(moment()))
const deepDiff = diff.format("D [day], H [hour and] m [min]")
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED** , it is totally correct now.

First of all Friday actually has sequence number `5`, so use it instead 4.
`const nextFriday = moment().weekday(5)` - this is correct Friday.

Next important thing is that *nearest* Friday is taken by default, it means that already passed Friday can be selected (for example if it is Satturday today). In such case we just need to add one week.

Here is working code snippet:

```js
function getWeekend() {
    const today = moment();
    const friday = moment().weekday(5);
    // check if wee need to add one week in case of previous Friday selected
    if (friday < today) { 
        friday.add(1, 'weeks');
    }
    friday.hours(18) // Weekend time: 18:00
    friday.minutes(0)
    friday.seconds(0)
    return friday.diff(moment(), 'hours');
}

const hoursToFriday = getWeekend();
console.log(`Friday 18:00 will be in ${hoursToFriday} hours`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is wrong because, if you run this code on a SATURDAY, it won't give you the NEXT friday, it will give you the previous friday

Comment: I did try it. That's why I said that.

Comment: Output is 53 hours for me at the moment, and it is correct amount of hours till next Friday.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I said. What I said is that if you run this code on a Saturday, it will give you the incorrect result. It gives you the correct result today, because today isn't Saturday.

Comment: Now I understood. Sorry for that, you are right in that case. Going to change my answer....

Comment: Just updated the answer. It works correctlt now. Thank you @TKoL

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/7ehoq06n/

If you just call `moment().weekday(5)` it will go to Friday of "this week", which means that if you're on a saturday, it will go to YESTERDAY.

If you want the next friday, always in the future, use this:

```
var today = moment();
var friday = moment().weekday(5);
if (friday < today) {
    friday.add(1, 'weeks');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Moment.js has a build in function .fromNow() it returns the time beween the given time and the local time. So the only 2 line you need to change are the .weekday(4) because friday is weekday(5). and call the .fromnow() function.

```js
console.log(getWeekend());
function getWeekend() {
    const nextFriday = moment().weekday(5);
    nextFriday.hours(18); // Weekend time: 18:00
    nextFriday.minutes(0);
    nextFriday.seconds(0);
    return nextFriday.fromNow();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Note that fromNow will return a string Moment.js has a build in solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can take hours difference using `(now - next Friday) / 60*60*1000` method, Try it:

```
const nextFriday = moment().day(5)
var hours = Math.abs(new Date() - nextFriday) / 36e5; 
console.log(hours);
```

Note: `36e5` is the scientific notation for 60*60*1000

Comment: Your way of calculating the next friday fails on saturday, see comments for Artem Arkhipov's answer